# find the most common name in textfile

Tags: java

I have this homework assignement, that I am stuck on.

I have to find the most commond name in the text file, for each line. If there is a tie, use the first name that had that many occurrences. If all names are unique, print the first name on the line.

The files input:
Benson Eric Eric Kim Kim Kim Jenny Nancy Nancy Paul Paul
Ethan Jamie Jamie Alyssa Alyssa Helene Helene Jessica Jessica.

The result: 
Most common: Kim
Most common: Jamie

This is what I get from my code: Paul and Jessica.

I need to hold the result from how many times the names have been repeated, but cannot see what I miss.

This is the code I have been trying.

```
public static void mostCommonNames(Scanner input)
 {

     int count = 0;
     int countName = 0;


     while(input.hasNextLine())
     {

        String commonName = "";
        String commonName1 = "";
       String line = input.nextLine();



       Scanner token = new Scanner(line);

       while(token.hasNext())
       {
            String name = "";
             int max = 0; 
             int longCurrent = 0;
             int i = 0;          

           String tokenName = token.next();


           if(tokenName.equals("Benson") || tokenName.equals("Eric") || 
              tokenName.equals("Kim") || tokenName.equals("Jenny") || 
              tokenName.equals("Nancy") || tokenName.equals("Paul") ||
              tokenName.equals("Ethan") || tokenName.equals("Jamie") || 
              tokenName.equals("Alyssa") || tokenName.equals("Helene") ||
              tokenName.equals("Jessica"))
           {                

             count++;


           }
           if(commonName.equals(tokenName))
           {

              countName++;

              if(i < countName)
              {

                 longCurrent = i;
              }

           }

           if(max < count)
           {
              commonName = tokenName;

           }

        }     

           System.out.print(commonName + " ");                        

    }

        System.out.print(countName + " ");              
}

}
```

Hope someone could help me with a guidance, not the result.

Comment: I'm not going to do the work for you, but if your class has covered any data structures yet, take a look at the HashMap class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a `Map<String, int> NameCount = new HashMap<String, int>();`
Initially assign key `0` to all. After than just increment the key value in the map for the each name repeated each time.

```
while(token.hasNext())
{
    String name = token.next();
    int count = NameCount.containsKey(name) ? NameCount.get(name) : 0;
    NameCount.put(name, count + 1);
}
```

After that just print the name with the highest key value or whatever the way you want. 
If you don't want to use HashMap then you can also maintain an integer array in which each element holds the count for each distinct name.

```
int NameCount[]=new int[TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_DISTINCT_NAMES];//array should be initialized to 0
while(token.hasNext())
{
    String name = token.next();
    NameCount[INDEX_ASSOCIATED_TO_NAME]++;
}
```

Be careful to increment only the index value associated to a specific name,
rest is the same.I think its sufficient...

Answer (score 0):

if the total number of names is always going to be the same you could add an int value for each name you have & +1 evertime if it finds the name corresponding to the int value you set, after you scan all the names compare the int values to see which one is the highest